# Indirect Proof of right $\triangle{ABC}$.

Tags: geometry

I am naturally terrible at indirect proofs and am struggling with this problem: Prove that the hypotenuse is the longest side of a right triangle indirectly.

So far, I have gotten to:

$(1)$ Assume that the hypotenuse is *not* the longest side of a right triangle.

---

I'm not sure what to do after that. Do I split it into two different cases and let $\text{leg}_1>\text{the hypotenuse}$ and $\text{leg}_2>\text{the hypotenuse}$ or do I ignore my first thought and proceed?

Tips on how to tackle any indirect proof problem is also very helpful!

Comment: It's important to know what tools (theorems) you have at your disposal to use. Do you know the Pythagorean Theorem? Do you know that sides opposite larger angles are longer?

Comment: Obviously this exercise is meant to be done without pre-supposing the Pythagorean theorem or the law of sines or the opposite angles law.  I would say you can assume the notions of internal and external lines, and all five Euclidean postulates (since the theorem is false in some non-Euclidean geometries).

Comment: I already have learned the triangle inequality theorem, and the Pythagorean Theorem... But what annoys me a bit is how this problem is common sense.

Comment: I'm glad everything's so obvious to you, @MarkFischler. Perhaps you could soften your tone a little bit for us mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without either of those two pre-supposed facts, using just the parallel postulate (which implies that the sum of the angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$):

Draw triangle $ABC$ with right angle at $C$, and suppose side $AC$ is the longest. Then construct a line segment $AD$ along line $AC$ with one end at $A$ and of length $AB$. Since $AB < AC$, $D$ lies on the lilne segment $AC$.

Now draw line segment $BD$.

Using the fact that the exterior angle of a triangle equals the sum of the two remote interior angles (this relies on the parallel postulate), angle $\angle BDA =90^\circ+\angle DBC$.  This implies $\angle BDA > 90^\circ$.

In isoceles triangle $BAD$, base angles $\angle BDA = \angle DBA$. So the sum of the angles in triangle $BAD$ is more than $90^\circ + 90^\circ + \angle CAB$, hence more than $180^\circ$.  This contradicts the sum of the angles of a triangle, so our supposition that line $AC$ is longest cannot be the case.  Similarly, $BC$ cannot be the longest.

Finally, suppose $AB$ is equal in length to one of the sides, say $AC$; then $\triangle CAB$ is iscoceles, and must contain two right angles, so the third angle has to be zero and that is not a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that if a side is longer than another then the angle opposite of the first is greater than the one opposing the second. Hence if the hypotenuse isn't the longest side, then one of the angle must be bigger than $90^{\circ}$. But then the sum of the angles will be more than $180^{\circ}$, hence a contradiction.

Additionally you can use the Pythagorean Theorem and use that: $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \implies c>a \text{ and } c>b$, as all squares of sides are non-negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

An indirect approach through geometry of circles...

The circumcircle of a right-angled triangle has the hypotenuse as a diameter. As there are no points on a circle further apart than twice the radius, the hypotenuse must be longer than the other two sides.

---

To see that $\triangle ABC$ with right-angle $\angle ABC$ has $AC$ as the diameter of a circle  which has $B$ at another point on the circumference, consider the following diagram:

[image]

$\triangle ADE$ is a half-size copy of $\triangle ABC$ , so $|AE| = |EC|$ (and $|AD| = |DB|$.

Since  $\angle EDB$ is also a right angle $\triangle BED$ is a flipped copy of $\triangle ADE$

Therefore $|EB|=|AE|$ and $A,B,C$ all lie on a circle centred on $E$, and $AC$ is a diameter of that circle.

---

Even without considering circles, the above construction shows that $|AE| = |EC|=|EB|$ (for $E$ the midpoint of $AC$). Call this distance $d$, and note $|AC| = 2d$

Then note that the triangle inequality gives that $|AB|\lt 2d = |AE|+|EB|$ and  $|BC|\lt 2d = |BE|+|EC|$, as desired.

Comment: At that chapter, we haven't learned about triangles inscribed in a circle... :/ (yet)

Comment: OK... this is a special (and fairly easy) case to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, but this theorem can come way before circle geometry is even developed.

Comment: @MarkFischler - OK, just the triangle inequality... :-)